# How to model collateral damage in Cortex Prime

Tags: gm-techniques, damage, cortex-prime

I'm running a superhero campaign in Cortex Prime. During a bank robbery scenario, one of my players decided to get into the bank by shattering the front window. In addition to looking cool, he hoped this approach might injure and/or startle the robbers. I had him roll a test to break the window, which he passed with flying colors, but then I was at a loss about what to do next, beyond saying, "It works; the window shatters."

In-universe, the front room of the bank should now be full of flying shards of glass. There are both robbers and innocent bystanders in the room. I'm aiming for a tone similar to your average Spider-Man movie: not super dark/gritty, but actions do have consequences. Shattering the window was a reckless act, and it should carry the risk that some of the good guys get hurt, as well as the possibility that some of the bad guys get hurt.

**How do I model this risk in Cortex Prime?** The rules for a test merely say that if the player passes, whatever they wanted to do happens. Clearly that means the window breaks, but does it also mean the robbers get injured and the bystanders don't? If so, how do I decide which of the robbers are injured and how badly? (The robbers were represented by a major GMC and a 2d6 mob.) Conversely, would bystanders be injured only if the player rolls a hitch? If so, which bystanders and how badly injured?

- One possible answer is for the GM to decide based on what feels appropriate. This is what I did in the moment: since the player didn't roll any hitches and passed the test (I think with a heroic success), I ruled that none of the bystanders were injured and the major GMC robber took d6 Injured stress. It worked, but it felt a bit arbitrary.
- In D&D, I imagine this scenario would lead to all the characters in the bank making dexterity saves to avoid being injured. Is there a similar mechanic in Cortex to have each character roll to avoid injury? Perhaps a test with a d6 difficulty plus the effect die from the PC's glass-shattering test?
- Another thought I had after the session was to add a Flying Glass trait to the location, which would probably go away at the end of the round (we were in action order). That would make it harder for characters in the bank to succeed at actions, but I'm not sure how it would lead to them being injured--especially the bystanders, who were huddled on the floor not taking any actions anyway.

I expect this type of scenario will come up again: a character creates a hazardous condition that could affect everyone in an area, both bad guys and good guys. What Cortex Prime game mechanics can I use to determine who gets hurt and who doesn't?

Answer (score 7):

#### When you think "collateral damage", you think "doom pool".

I mean, I do, anyway.

If you're not using the mod, I'd consider starting to. It started out in *Marvel Heroic Roleplaying* and gives a lot of useful hooks for superheroic storytelling, where you need to keep your head on a swivel for ways to escalate a scene and heroes often use their powers in risky ways.

Captain America can take a moment to recover and clear his physical stress, stepping up a **Super-Soldier Program** die in the process, but adding that stress die to the doom pool as something goes unnoticed. Wolverine can go berserk and borrow a die from the doom pool to attack with, then step it up and give it back as chaos ensues. A younger Cyclops can add his emotional stress to an attack involving **Force Blast**, but Scotty ain't careful when he's mad and the same die also goes into the doom pool.

So in your case, using some fairly standard SFX for boosting assets, here's how you do. These aren't features to add to any powerset in particular, just things you keep in your toolbox if you need something temporary or something dangerous:

> **Fleeting Asset.** When you create an Asset, if it only lasts until the next time you act, step up the effect die.
>
> **Perilous Asset.** When you create an Asset that also endangers you, your fellow heroes, or innocent bystanders, add a d6 and step up the effect die, then add an equal die to the doom pool. (If you're creating a fleeting asset, do this before you step up the effect die for being fleeting.)

"Fleeting Asset" is mimicking an earlier structure from Cortex+ that doesn't seem to have made the leap to Cortex Prime. It suits situations like the temporary advantage you and your allies have from bursting through the window and sending glass flying.

Anyway, once you've put that die in the doom pool you can spend out of the doom pool however makes sense. Are the glass shards now a Complication? Is some villain who's literally out for blood going to morb his way onto the scene? Did you really do a number on the hostages and now you have to split the party so some of you can evacuate them? (And what do you roll against to evacuate them? Say it with me, kids: doom pool!) All of these and more can be true, if the doom pool's big enough to spend on them.

Comment: Interesting. I decided not to use doom pool because it felt too abstract, and also I like the plot point economy a lot. I'll give it another look, though. I like the Fleeting/Perilous Asset ideas, and I think they could be adapted to a non-doom-pool game too.

Comment: @DLosc The abstraction is kind of an asset in this case. It cuts through considerations of what might be fair to add to the scene when it seems like things should get worse for the PCs but there's no clear mechanism for how: it's always fair to spend out of the doom pool. That doesn't mean that you abandon the narrative when you do it. You should still explain what's going on, but there's less expectation that you need to justify it in the narrative.

Answer (score 6):

For "who gets hurt" : Either the player keeps multiple effects dice and targets multiple enemies, or you choose which enemies were closer to the window (you could even let the player choose). Then, depending on the effect die, damage is taken by the robbers. (d6 or below : the major GMC takes a d6 complication OR one of the mob dice get stepped down to d4, d8 or above : the major GMC takes a complication of the same size OR one of the mob dice gets completely removed)

For the collateral damage :

My first thought is to say you have done the right thing, and collateral damage is something to apply to hitches.

My second thought is that, in the book, it is said that you can create a d6 asset as the result of a successful test, even if it was not the main purpose. So maybe it is possible that, even as the result of a successful test, you could create a d6 complication if whatever you do causes the situation to worsen. (Though that is not in the rules)

So it could be your first and third options. Your second option is not bad per se, but it might bog down play by forcing everyone to roll to not get hurt.

As for your third option, the d6 scene complication might come up into play if the players roll any hitch on their roll (even if it is only narratively) : if the players roll hitches, they get hurt by the glass.

And in the case of a hitch making things worse, you could have the character suffer a d6 complication "Hurt bystanders", which can be used to make the characters feel guilty or to make further tests harder!

Please feel free to correct me or tell me if things do not make sense, my brain is all over the place when trying to explain the rules.

Comment: This is a much more detailed answer than mine. Great suggestions!

Comment: I like the idea of a Hurt Bystanders complication. It's taking me a while to wrap my head around the idea of treating bystanders not as separate characters but as "set dressing": only important insofar as they affect the PCs' story. Sounds callous, but then that's also how it works in most superhero movies.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few suggestions, in two main parts: how to decide how well this works, and how to represent the consequences. You don’t mention how heroic or gritty the tone of your game is, though, and what works will depend a lot on that. Any page numbers are references to the Cortex Prime rulebook.

### Degree of success - effect dice

As mentioned on page 21 under “Effect Dice in Opposition”, an effect die is still chosen in a test. Unless you’re using the “No Effect Dice” mod (page 25), then the size of the effect die can be used to determine the degree of success (see “Effect Dice” on page 20) - in this case how much damage the robbers take. While this is often translated directly to the size of an asset or the amount of stress inflicted, that doesn’t have to be so, especially in a case like this where their action is broad and could have negative consequences. As long as you set the stakes before the roll, you can explain that the bigger the effect die, the more robbers are caught in the blast. You could also have bystanders injured on a lower effect die, or only when rolling a hitch. Which works best really depends on how realistic and dangerous this has to feel to suit the tone of your game.

I note that you said they passed with flying colours, so also remember they get to step up the effect die for every five points over the difficulty.

As it says on page 21, *usually* there’s no reason to compare a player’s effect die to the opposition’s effect die in a test. But this is a case where it might be appropriate - perhaps if the robbers can choose a bigger die, they might shield behind some bystanders who also take damage, the amount of which is still determined by the player’s die. But that also leads us to…

### Consequences - temporary traits and Complications

You mention adding “Flying Glass” as a trait on the bank, which could work, but I’d instead be thinking of longer term consequences. As you mention it’d only be flying momentarily, during which time it is added to player rolls to hinder the robbers.

As an alternative or addition, you could have a complication of “Broken Glass” that persists during the scene. The heroes and robbers might be able to mostly ignore it, but it will make saving bystanders from harm more difficult, especially if they’d been told to lie on the floor or who get shoved out of the way by the robbers.

Mentioning this as a likely outcome to the player breaking the glass upfront is probably appropriate, too.

Comment: Good question about the tone. I'm aiming for a tone similar to your average Spider-Man movie: some light moments, some serious moments, but not super dark/gritty. So "bystanders get some cuts from the glass" is on the table, but "bystanders are horribly killed and lying in a pool of blood" is not.

Comment: I like the idea of basing the outcome on the size of the effect die but not one-for-one. I think I made it sound like the goal of the test was to injure the robbers, but the main goal was to get inside the bank in an unexpected way. Injuring the robbers was merely a hoped-for side effect. So the questions of whether any robbers and/or bystanders got injured wouldn't come into play at all unless the test succeeded. I could see "you succeed with a d4 effect die" translating to "you break the glass but slightly injure a civilian."