# Should GM characters ever roll tests against difficulty dice?

Tags: actions, npc, cortex-prime

I'm running a superhero campaign in Cortex Prime. During our [bank robbery session](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/210307/how-to-model-collateral-damage-in-cortex-prime), one of the robbers managed to escape with the cash and jump in the getaway car, which started to drive off. Our heroes were able to take out the driver from a distance, at which point the robber in the passenger seat attempted to grab the wheel and keep driving. As his action in the action order, I had him roll a test against a d12 difficulty to take control of the car. (He passed, and was able to get a short distance down the street before the PCs caught up to him.)

In hindsight, though, I get the feeling that game moderator characters rolling tests isn't how Cortex Prime is designed to work. Specifically, the players asked whether they could activate 1s rolled during the test as opportunities (either from the GMC's dice, or the difficulty dice, or both). I decided that they couldn't, but it feels like a weird corner case that's not supposed to happen.

**Should a GMC ever make a test against difficulty dice rolled by the GM?** If not, how should I represent a GMC's action that might succeed or fail but is not directly opposed by the PCs? Is the answer different for an ordinary test than for an action taken during action order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If there are actions to take, GMCs can take them.

Yeah, the rules aren't stopping you here:

> [A]nything a player character **or GMC** does is called an action. If you want to carry out an action, you declare it, gather up your pool, and roll the dice, just as if you were starting a contest. Instead of moving to a back and forth escalation like a contest, the action is opposed by a reaction, which is either the target of the action rolling their own dice, or a difficulty set by the GM rolling difficulty dice. If the reaction beats the action’s total, the action fails.
>
> -- *Cortex Prime*, "Action-Based Resolution", emphasis mine

GMCs taking action in this manner act the way players would when rolling against difficulty dice: they roll their dice first, and the difficulty dice are rolled afterward.

However, Cortex Prime is very much a game that wants PCs to be taking the lead and rolling pretty much all the time. There is no distinction in the rules for opportunities about **why** the GM is rolling dice; when the GM rolls a 1, that's an opportunity. Even if they're rolling GMCs against the GM's difficulty dice, both sides of that are still a single opportunity.

If that seems a little generous to the PCs, well, consider it a reason to think twice about how the GMCs could be contesting a PC instead. Maybe in this case you'd drop some kind of **d10 driverless car (not that kind)** complication on the getaway vehicle that the remaining getaway crew could try to step down as a reward for winning a pursuit contest against a PC. After all, if the PCs aren't actively pursuing, why can't the crew just pull the handbrake and take all the time they need?

Comment: Makes sense. I was getting hung up on this bit from the Tests and Contests section: "Occasionally, the player sets the difficulty for a GMC's test. In this case, the player rolls first and the GM rolls to beat the difficulty set by the player" (p 18). Does that apply to all GMC tests outside of action order, or does it apply only if the PC would have a say in how difficult the GMC's action is?

Comment: And what should I do with 1s rolled by the GMC and by the difficulty dice? Can players activate all of them as opportunities, or only some, or none?

Comment: @DLosc Updated the answer, I think this is good for your questions?

Comment: Yes, that update is excellent, thank you! It gets at the disconnect I was feeling between what I was doing and what was "supposed" to happen. The example of how to turn the test into a contest vs the PCs is helpful.